# Neural Network Number of Output Layer Nodes

Tags: neural-network, supervised-learning

I'm training a supervised neural network for six different classes. How to decide the minimum and maximum number of nodes for output layer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you want to have as many neurons as there are outputs in the output layer in a classification problem. Putting less will require you to add more hidden layers in order to abstract the data even more to represent it in a more compact form. (i.e. representing digits 1-10 with only 4 output slots requires you to represent your data in another form, such as binary, which means your neural network needs an extra hidden layer to decompose your data even more.)

**If the Neural Network is a classifier the output layer should have one node per class label in your model.**

Answer (score 2):

### - If the NN is a **regressor** then the output layer is going to be a **single node(neuron)** that will return a value.

### - If the NN is a **classifier** then the output layer is going to be a single node(neuron) **except** if you use *Softmax* where one node per class label is needed.